# Android onHandleIntent does not process database query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

On device startup, I want to get some values from a SQLite database. I have started an IntentService successfully on boot  using a BroadcastReceiver, and it prints out that it has started. When I go in onHandleIntent and run a query, it doesn't print out the database query.

IntentService (again, it successfully starts):

```
public class QueuedService extends IntentService
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs; 
    DBHelper dbHelper; 
    Context context; 

    public QueuedService() 
    {
        super("QueuedService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    { 
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); 
        Log.v("QueuedService", "Received start id " + startId + " : " + intent); 

        return START_STICKY; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.v("QueuedService", "Started Service"); // THIS prints

        context = getApplicationContext(); 
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);

        List<QueuePostTwitter> qTwit = dbHelper.getQueueTwitter(); 
        Log.v("QueuedService", Integer.toString(qTwit.size())); // this doesn't print ?
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AutostartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            Intent backgroundService = new Intent(context, StartBackgroundSyncService.class);       
            context.startService(backgroundService);

            Intent queuedService = new Intent(context, QueuedService.class); 
            context.startService(queuedService); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in the line above that log, debug it and understand why is it not logging?

Comment: @joao2fast4u it doesn't do anything when I do that

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the first log line, it will surely stop there, if you say it is logging that line. From there, go line to line to understand what is wrong.